# Background Task to send an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

MVC 5.1, .NET 4.5

In our simple web site we need to send an email. Our email service is called by a Post back event and it sends the email, then builds a result page and returns it.

This slows the page since the page has to wait for the synchronous email to be sent.

If we run the email in a different thread, can the site continue on to create the page and return it to the user as the email is being processed, or will a long running task cause the page to be not rendered.

Basically, can I send am email non blocking for performance reasons.

Note: We can't send the email request to a service or other system.

Comment: [`SmtpClient.SendAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Simply changing to  smtp.SendMailAsync(message); worked. Wow, that was easy as!

Comment: On top, it should not be needed. If a sending email slows you down more than 0.2 seconds something is really odd in your email setup - like not using a local relay server.

Comment: Poor man's mailer service is the SMTP from Gmail....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you you use built in `SmtpClient` you can use [`SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
smtpClient.SendMailAsync(new MailMessage{ ... });
```

> Sends the specified message to an SMTP server for delivery as an asynchronous operation

Comment: It's not allowed to call SendMailAsync for the second time, if the first sending is not completed.

Comment: @Der_Meister never said it's allowed. `SmtpClient` can send only one email at a time.

Comment: Right, it's just a warning for readers. For many apps it's better to use long-living SmtpClient instance, because it keeps SMTP connection opened. However, need to make sure that the client processes only one message at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Calling StartNew is functionally equivalent to creating a task by using one of its constructors, and then calling the Task.Start method to schedule the task for execution.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
         //do somethings
});
```

Example:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
         SendMail("Hello world", "email@yahoo.com", "TEST");
});

public static bool SendMail(string subject, string to, string body)
    {
        string fromMailAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailAddress"];
        string fromMailPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailPassword"];
        string fromMailName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailName"];

        var networkConfig = new NetworkCredential(fromMailAddress, fromMailPassword);
        var mailServer = new SmtpClient()
        {
            Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpHost"],
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = networkConfig
        };
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"]))
            mailServer.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"]);

        var message = new MailMessage()
        {
            Subject = subject,
            SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        };

        //message send config
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
        message.From = new MailAddress(fromMailAddress, fromMailName);
        message.Body = body;

        try
        {
            mailServer.SendAsync(message, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that Hadi, I found  smtp.SendMailAsync(message) did the trick all for me.

Comment: That is a serious lot of code that is just showing some people still are not in modern .NET ;) As in: unneeded.